# Django Createview save form and redirect to page according to the id of the foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am studying the CBV in Django.

I've got a page of a `Flat`. I want a user to be able to add some pictures of the apartment on that page.

The photos of the flat are stored in the model and connected with `User` and `Flat` models. My model looks like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_path = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Фотография')
    photo_user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Агент, добавивший фото')
    photo_flat = models.ForeignKey(Flat, verbose_name='Квартира')
    photo_description = models.CharField(verbose_name='Описание', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

My goal: If a user adds some pictures and presses the button, the pictures will be saved to the model. The user will then be redirected to the same detail view of the flat and will see their added pictures.

I've tried different options, but I don't have enough skills to handle this problem.

The first thing that makes me confused is the `template_name` variable in the `CreateView`. My CreateView looks like this:

```
class PhotoUploadView(CreateView):
    form_class = PhotoUploadModelForm
    template_name = 'photo_upload.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.instance.photo_user = self.request.user
        self.instance.photo_flat_id = self.kwargs['flat_id']
        form.save()
        return super(PhotoUploadView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('flatdetail')
```

What if I don't want to show any different page to the user? I want them to be redirected to the same flat detail view after posting the pictures. I can't delete `template_name` from `CreateView` because of the following error:

```
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

What have I achieved in the `CreateView` above?

The second confusing thing: I posted the pictures and was redirected to  `redirect.html` but not the flat detail view. That's bad. But my pictures weren't saved either. That's very bad. I've tried to change `redirect.html` to `flatdetail.html` but, of course, it shows the page with no additional information such as rooms, size, price and such.

What should I do to achieve two things in this particular situation:

1. Save the data
2. Redirect the user to the flat detail view after adding some photos.

Additional information:
my `urls.py`

```
 url(r'^dev/flat/(?P<flat_id>[0-9]+)/$', views_dev.flat_ajax, name='flatdetail'),
 url(r'^dev/photo-update/(?P<flat_id>[0-9]+)/$', views_dev.PhotoUploadView.as_view(), name='image-update')
```

my `forms.py`

```
class PhotoUploadModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['photo_path']
```

My form in the flatdetail template:

```
<form action="/dev/photo-update/{{flat.id}}/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token%}
    <input type="file" multiple>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Since you've used the code from my answer to your previous question, you should accept that answer.

Comment: Did you succeed, or so you need more help? If my answer was "the answer" would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're mixing up two things at the moment.

Your `PhotoUploadView` is completely seperate from your flat detail view. The `template_name` variable inside the `PhotoUploadView` is the template that will be used when loading the upload page. So this should be pointing to whatever HTML you want to use for the file upload.

```
template_name = 'flat_upload_photo.html'
```

I'm noticing your current `get_success_url()` function is not indented correctly. This could lead to the function not getting recognized inside the class and this therefor not being used. I'm not sure if this is just an indentation error on StackOverflow or also present in your actual code. I also see the function does not have the correct arguments for a redirect to take place. If we looks at your `urls.py` we see that the url for `flatdetail` requires a flat ID. So make sure your `get_success_url()` is indented correctly (inside the class) and looks like the following:

```
def get_success_url():
    return reverse('flatdetail', args=(self.kwargs['flat_id'],)
```

`args=(self.kwargs['flat_id'],)` makes sure we pass a tuple with arguments to the URL we're searching for. Specifically the ID of the object we want to return to. This is required because the url `flatdetail` URL you've specified in `urls.py` requires a flat ID.

Thirdly I think the reason your `PhotoUploadView` does not actually upload a photo has to do with the fact your accessing `self.instance.photo_user` instead of `form.instance.photo_user`. It's also not necessary to do `form.save()` at that point, since this will happen when you call the `super()` function.

I'm not entirely sure what's going on in your `form_valid()`. Perhaps if you could clarify what's going wrong there (any errors?) I would be able to better help you.

Comment: Thank you for help. When I change the function to the statement `success_url = reverse('flatdetail')` I've got an error `The included URLconf 'django_project.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.` The error is happening when I try to load the page of the flat. I change the function to `reverse_lazy `and now I'm encountering with the same error  trying post the pictures

Comment: WIth `reverse_lazy` the error is actually gone but I have no redirect back to the page of the flat. Django renders `redirect.html` which is empty page and displays it. Photoes aren't saved either. I can see no errors

Comment: @mailman_73 I've updated my answer. I was actually wrong about using the `success_url` variable. Have you updated the values in `form_valid()` with the correct `form.instance.photo_user` values?

Comment: thank you for help again. But it still just returns blank `redirect.html` instead of redirect to the same page. Does it happen because my data in form isn't valid? And instead of return `flatdetail view` django returns template of CBV?

Or maybe problem is here `<form action="/dev/photo-update/{{flat.id}}/" method="POST">`? The form is stored in `flatdetail template` and has no personal templage/page

Comment: @mailman_73 technically you don't need the form `action` set to anything (it defaults to the same page if you leave it empty, which is what you want). If you add `print "Form valid!"` to the `form_valid()` function you should see this output in the server logs the moment you posted correct data. If you don't see this output it means something is going wrong when you post the data. This could be a couple of things, which might require asking a new question.